# How to convert encoded DER certitificate to NSString format?

Tags: objective-c, macos, der, security-framework

I’m working on certificate based authentication for my application. I can able to get the certificate from keychain, it’s in DER format with CFData type. I need to send the certificate CFData to server for authentication, is it possible to convert the certificate data into NSString format?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `CFData` reference to `NSData` and then use `base64EncodedStringWithOptions:` to encode the data into a string.